# Can a desktop AIR app be run on an Android device?

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, apk

I have an Adobe AIR desktop application, built in Flex Builder 3,  that I want to run on an android device, specifically a Samsung Galaxy Tablet. I have put the application on an emulator, going through the steps of installing AIR on the emulator, packaging the application as an APK, and installing the application on the emulator. However, when I click the application, it does not run. 
Here is my question: is this even possible? Can a desktop application be run on a mobile device with no changes to the code, or does it need to be converted to a mobile application before compiling? Thanks for any and all input,

T

Comment: In theory it should be doable; but I doubt you'll see acceptable performance.  You should take a look at Burrito on labs with the Flex Mobile stuff to see about converting your app to covert to something more appropriate for a mobile device.  I'm not sure why the app isn't running, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is yes you can deploy that to a mobile device. As far as changes to the code is concerned, the answer is it depends. If it's a simple application, you shouldn't have to change anything.

Since there is no way (from what I understand) to create .apk files in Flex Builder 3, I am assuming you are going through the ADT command line to package it?

And you are following all the steps on 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffb.html

Once we have that covered, other questions would be: Are you using any modules or a framework? Any error messages?

From what I understand, Android doesn't support mx components, so depending on what you are doing there, yes you might have to change the code in order to make it work for Android.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Yes, I built it in Flex 3, but went through the command line to package it, following the steps on the link you included. The end of your response confuses me a little, I am not sure I know what modules or a framework is. Do you mean Flex framework? AIR? Actionscript? My ignorance may be showing. I believe I use the Flex framework. I also use mx components, as well as some custom ones. So since my application is written using almost exclusive mx components, I would have to change it to be able to run on android? thanks,T